# Morlet wavelet transformation function returns nonsensical plot

Tags: matlab, plot, wavelet

I have written a matlab function (Version 7.10.0.499 (R2010a)) to evaluate incoming FT signal and calculate the morlet wavelet for the signal. I have a similar program, but I needed to make it more readable and closer to mathematical lingo. The output plot is supposed to be a 2D plot with colour showing the intensity of the frequencies. My plot seems to have all frequencies the same per time. The program does make an fft per row of time for each frequency, so I suppose another way to look at it is that the same line repeats itself per step in my for loop. The issue is I have checked with the original program, which does return the correct plot, and I cannot locate any difference beyond what I named the values and how I organized the code.

```
function[msg] = mile01_wlt(FT_y, f_mn, f_mx, K, N, F_s)
%{
Fucntion to perform a full wlt of a morlet wavelett.
optimization of the number of frequencies to be included. 
FT_y satisfies the FT(x) of 1 envelope and is our ft signal.
f min and max enter into the analysis and are decided from 
the f-image for optimal values.
While performing the transformation there are different scalings
on the resulting "intensity".
Plot is made with a 2D array and a colour code for intensity. 
version 05.05.2016
%}

%--------------------------------------------------------------%
%{
tableofcontents:
    1: determining nr. of analysis f, prints and readies f's to be used.
    2: ensuring correct orientation of FT_y
    3:defining arrays
    4: declaring waveletdiagram and storage of frequencies
    5: for-loop over all frequencies:
    6: reducing file to manageable size by truncating time.
    7: marking plot to highlight ("randproblemer")
    8: plotting waveletdiagram
%}

%--------------------------------------------------------------%
%1: determining nr. of analysis f, prints and readies f's to be used.
    DF = floor( log(f_mx/f_mn) / log(1+( 1/(8*K) ) ) ) + 1;% f-spectre analysed
    nr_f_analysed = DF              %output to commandline
    f_step = (f_mx/f_mn)^(1/(DF-1)); % multiplicative step for new f_a
    f_a = f_mn; %[Hz] frequency of analysis
    T = N/F_s; %[s] total time sampled
    C = 2.0; % factor to scale Psi

%--------------------------------------------------------------%
%2: ensuring correct orientation of FT_y
    siz = size(FT_y);
    if (siz(2)>siz(1)) 
        FT_y = transpose(FT_y);
    end;

%--------------------------------------------------------------%    
%3:defining arrays
    t = linspace(0, T*(N-1)/N, N); %[s] timespan
    f = linspace(0, F_s*(N-1)/N, N); %[Hz] f-specter

%--------------------------------------------------------------%
%4: declaring waveletdiagram and storage of frequencies
    WLd = zeros(DF,N); % matrix of DF rows and N columns for storing our wlt
    f_store = zeros(1,DF); % horizontal array for storing DF frequencies

%--------------------------------------------------------------%
%5: for-loop over all frequencies:
    for jj = 1:DF
        o = (K/f_a)*(K/f_a); %factor sigma
        Psi = exp(- 0*(f-f_a).*(f-f_a)); % FT(\psi) for 1 envelope
        Psi = Psi - exp(-K*K)*exp(- o*(f.*f)); % correctional element
        Psi = C*Psi; %factor. not set in stone
        
        %next step fits 1 row in the WLd (3 alternatives)
        %WLd(jj,:) = abs(ifft(Psi.*transpose(FT_y))); 
        WLd(jj,:) = sqrt(abs(ifft(Psi.*transpose(FT_y))));
        %WLd(jj,:) = sqrt(abs(ifft(Psi.*FT_y))); %for different array sizes
                                                %and emphasizes weaker parts.
        %prep for next round
        f_store (jj) = f_a; % storing used frequencies
        f_a = f_a*f_step; % determines the next step
    end;

%--------------------------------------------------------------%
%6: reducing file to manageable size by truncating time.
    P = floor( (K*F_s) / (24*f_mx) );%24 not set in stone
    using_every_P_point = P %printout to cmdline for monitoring
    N_P = floor(N/P);
    points_in_time = N_P %printout to cmdline for monitoring
    % truncating WLd and time
    WLd2 = zeros(DF,N_P);
    for jj = 1:DF
        for ii = 1:N_P
            WLd2(jj,ii) = WLd(jj,ii*P);
        end
    end
    t_P = zeros(1,N_P);
    for ii = 1:N_P % set outside the initial loop to reduce redundancy
        t_P(ii) = t(ii*P);
    end
    
%--------------------------------------------------------------%
%7: marking plot to highlight boundary value problems
    maxval = max(WLd2);%setting an intensity
    mxv = max(maxval);
    % marks in wl matrix
    for jj= 1:DF
        m = floor( K*F_s / (P*pi*f_store(jj)) ); %finding edges of envelope
        WLd2(jj,m) = mxv/2; % lower limit
        WLd2(jj,N_P-m) = mxv/2;% upper limit
    end
    
%--------------------------------------------------------------%
%8: plotting waveletdiagram
    figure;
    imagesc(t_P, log10(f_store), WLd2, 'Ydata', [1 size(WLd2,1)]);
    set(gca, 'Ydir', 'normal');
    xlabel('Time [s]');
    ylabel('log10(frequency [Hz])');
    %title('wavelet power spectrum'); % for non-sqrt inensities
    title('sqrt(wavelet power spectrum)'); %when calculating using sqrt
    colorbar('location', 'southoutside');
    msg = 'done.';
```

There are no error message, so I am uncertain what exactly I am doing wrong.
Hope I followed all the guidelines. Otherwise, I apologize.

edit:
my calling program:
% establishing parameters
N = 2^(16); % | number of points to sample
F_s = 3.2e6; % Hz | samplings frequency
T_t = N/F_s;  % s | length in seconds of sample time
f_c = 2.0e5; % Hz | carrying wave frequency
f_m = 8./T_t; % Hz | modulating wave frequency
w_c = 2*pi*f_c; % Hz | angular frequency("omega") of carrying wave
w_m = 2*pi*f_m; % Hz | angular frequency("omega") of modulating wave

```
% establishing parameter arrays
t = linspace(0, T_t, N);

% function variables
T_h = 2*f_m.*t; % dimless | 1/2 of the period for square signal

% combined carry and modulated wave
% y(t) eq. 1):
y_t = 0.5.*cos(w_c.*t).*(1+cos(w_m.*t)); 
% y(t) eq. 2):
%     y_t = 0.5.*cos(w_c.*t)+0.25*cos((w_c+w_m).*t)+0.25*cos((w_c-w_m).*t);
%square wave
sq_t = cos(w_c.*t).*(1 - mod(floor(t./T_h), 2)); % sq(t)

% the following can be exchanged between sq(t) and y(t) 

plot(t, y_t)
% plot(t, sq_t)
xlabel('time [s]');
ylabel('signal amplitude');
title('plot of harmonically modulated signal with carrying wave');
% title('plot of square modulated signal with carrying wave');
figure()
hold on

% Fourier transform and plot of freq-image
FT_y = mile01_fftplot(y_t, N, F_s);
% FT_sq = mile01_fftplot(sq_t, N, F_s);

% Morlet wavelet transform and plot of WLdiagram
%determining K, check t-image
K_h = 57*4; % approximation based on 1/4 of an envelope, harmonious
%determining f min and max, from f-image
f_m = 1.995e5; % minimum frequency. chosen to showcase all relevant f
f_M = 2.005e5; % maximum frequency. chosen to showcase all relevant f
%calling wlt function.
name = 'mile'
msg = mile01_wlt(FT_y, f_m, f_M, K_h, N, F_s)
siz = size(FT_y);
if (siz(2)>siz(1)) 
    FT_y = transpose(FT_y);
end;
name = 'arnt'
msg = arnt_wltransf(FT_y, f_m, f_M, K_h, N, F_s)
```

The time image has a constant frequency, but the amplitude oscillates resempling a gaussian curve. My code returns a sharply segmented image over time, where each point in time holds only 1 frequency. It should reflect a change in intensity across the spectra over time.
hope that helps and thanks!

Comment: Did you have a look at the data which you want to input into the plot? If so, is the data 'correct' in your understanding? If not, then not the plot is the problem, but if yes, you could simply give us the data and tell us how you want to make the plot look like :-)

Comment: Why are you doing a wavelet transform on the FFT output?

Comment: the morlet wavelet can be broken down into single "envelopes" these can in turn be broken up into what is essentially

ifft(fft(x)*fft(psi))

the psi is an analytical solution which I perform for each step and the fft(x)
is the signal I send in

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. There is a 0 rather than an o in the first instance of Psi. Thinking I'll maybe rename the value as sig or something. besides this the code works. sorry for the trouble there